# How to compile ClojureScript inside Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I want to compile ClojureScript inside Clojure and am having some problems. I would like to do something like this:

```
(def x '(map (fn [n] (* n n n)) [1 2 3 4]))
(cljs->js x)
```

where `cljs->js` returns JavaScript code. I guess [Himera](http://himera.herokuapp.com/index.html) does something similar (first reading ClojureScript from a string), but I don't know enough about ClojureScript to figure it out.

Is there are simple solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you look at the Himera code? [Here](https://github.com/fogus/himera/blob/master/src/clj/himera/server/cljs.clj) is where the code sent by the UI is compiled, which basically calls the cljs.compiler from the clojurescript project. Note that Himera is probably a lot more complex than what you are asking for, probably you just need to get the "compilation" function working

Answer (score 0):

once you have the clojurescript dependencies sorted out (which is it's own question) then you can just call the clojurescript `emit` function. this is used in the [Clutch project](https://github.com/clojure-clutch/clutch/) (couchdb for clojure+clojurescript). it basically looks like this:

```
(js/emit (aget doc "_id") nil)
```